# Index maintenance operations that are ONLINE in Standard Edition: Is table Read-Write or Read-Only?

Tags: sql-server

As we understand it, related to SQL Server 2008 and above:

```
ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE
```

Is on ON LINE operation in ALL flavors of SQL Server.

```
ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD
```

Is a BLOCKING operation, unless you have SQL Server Enterprise Edition.... (and even with the Enterprise Edition, is blocking when rebuilding clustered indexes)

If the above is all correct, the question is:

During an `ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE` operation, is the table available for read and write, or are writes blocked?

Comment: Writes are not directly blocked, although there are some schema-related locks taken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> During an ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE operation, is the table available for read and write, or are writes blocked?

REORGANIZE is always a online operation and single threaded operation but does not holds blocking locks. When you reorganize there is option to `allow_page_locks =ON or OFF` if you keep this value off you might get error like index cannot be reorganized as it cannot take page level lock so its better to reorganize index with option `allow_page_locks =ON`. So yes table is available for read write operation locks are taken as pointed in the option but as I said it does not holds blocking locks

As per [Microsoft Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189076.aspx)

Turning off page and row locking might or might not be acceptable because the weekly batch update will block the concurrent readers from accessing the table while the update runs. If the batch job only changes a few rows or pages, you can change the locking level to allow row or page level locking, which will enable other sessions to read from the table without blocking. If the batch job has a large number of updates, obtaining an exclusive lock on the table may be the best way to ensure the batch job finishes efficiently.

> ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD
>   Is a BLOCKING operation, unless you have SQL Server Enterprise Edition.... (and even with the Enterprise Edition, is blocking when rebuilding clustered indexes)

Even index rebuild in enterprise edition do takes short term locks as per [Paul Randal Article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-19-misconceptions-around-index-rebuilds-allocation-bulk_logged-mode-locking/) Online index operations need to take two very short-term table locks. An S (Shared) table lock at the start of the operation to force all write plans that could touch the index to recompile, and a SCH-M (Schema-Modification – think of it as an Exclusive) table lock at the end of operation to force all read and write plans that could touch the index to recompile.

Comment: +1 also useful to note that reorg isn't an "all-or-nothing" operation. If you let it work for an hour and then cancel it, you still get an hour's worth of reorg.